# Get Specific Key Value From Exif Data Using Imagick / PHP

Tags: php, upload, associative-array, imagick, exif

I'm using the Imagick image library with PHP and would like to store the width and height values from the EXIF data of an uploaded image. I can loop through the data to list all of the values, but I can't work out how to extract the specific width and height. There's no point in using the array position because obviously images will all have different EXIF data and such values won't always be in the same array position?

```
// new Imagick instance for uploaded files (the $temp variable relates to a foreach loop that saves the uploaded images in temporary memory)
$image = new Imagick($temp);

/* Get the EXIF information */
$exifArray = $image->getImageProperties();

/* Loop trough the EXIF properties */
foreach ($exifArray as $name => $property)
{
    echo "{$name} => {$property}<br />\n"; 
}
```

This prints out the key/values, an example of which are:

```
exif:FocalPlaneResolutionUnit => 3
exif:FocalPlaneXResolution => 49807360/32768
exif:FocalPlaneYResolution => 49807360/32768
exif:ImageLength => 876
exif:ImageWidth => 1313
exif:ISOSpeedRatings => 100
exif:Make => Canon
exif:MaxApertureValue => 3/1
exif:MeteringMode => 5
exif:Model => Canon EOS 6D
exif:Orientation => 1
```

How do I target a specific property value e.g. `ImageWidth`. The Imagick docs are not particularly helpful?

Also height seems to be outputted as `ImageLength`, which is also confusing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you already have an associative array with keys in it, so use those keys - either they exist, or they don't, but the keys will always be the same - hence you can always use the same literals:

```
$height =   $exifArray['exif:ImageLength']?? 0;
$width =    $exifArray['exif:ImageWidth']?? 0;
```

"[ImageLength](https://exiv2.org/tags.html)" is the correct name for that EXIF tag ([official standard](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-008-2012_E.pdf)). Historically a picture was (like bitmaps today still are) one line of pixels, cut at arbitrary positions to move to the next (display) line. Sometimes a width wasn't even needed because it could be assumed as per format. That's why "height" is a rather modern term, while EXIF was published back in 1995.